# Cubic bezier curve segment

Tags: math, graphics, coordinates, bezier

If I have the 4 points describing a Bezier curve P1, P2, P3, P4 (where P1 and P4 are the end points of the curve and P2 and P3 are the control points of the curve), how could I find the points that describes only a segment of this bezier curve?

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878862/drawing-part-of-a-bezier-curve-by-reusing-a-basic-bezier-curve-function) which is exactly what I am looking for but the answer seems wrong. If I set t0=0 and t1=1 in the equations which should represent the entire bezier curve, the resulting points are not valid. They are not equal to the original points.

It seems that the solution is related to the De Casteljau's algorithm, but I can't understand how it works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, [De Casteljau's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm) is the way to go.

## Parametrization

If your curve isn't correctly parametrized from *t*=0 trough *t*=1, then it seems you're using the wrong equation to descibe your curve. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves) has the correct formula for you:

> B(*t*) = (1−*t*)<sup>3</sup> *P*<sub>1</sub> + 3(1−*t*)<sup>2</sup>*t* *P*<sub>2</sub> + 3(1−*t*)*t*<sup>2</sup> *P*<sub>3</sub> + *t*<sup>3</sup> *P*<sub>4</sub>
>
> [I adjusted the indices from the zero-based form in Wikipedia to the one-based from your question.]

If you set *t*=0, you get *P*<sub>1</sub>, your starting point. If you set *t*=1, you get *P*<sub>4</sub>, your endpoint. In between, the shape of the curve is determined by those points and the two control points *P*<sub>2</sub> and *P*<sub>3</sub>.

## De Casteljau's algorithm

Let *t* be the parameter where you want to cut your curve. Let's say you want to keep only the initial part. You draw the three lines from *P*<sub>1</sub> to *P*<sub>2</sub>, from there to *P*<sub>3</sub> and from there to *P*<sub>4</sub>. Each of these lines you divide at a the fraction *t* of its length, i.e. the length of the line before the dividing point relates to the entire length as *t* : 1. You now have three new points *P*<sub>12</sub> through *P*<sub>34</sub>. Do the same again to obtain two points *P*<sub>123</sub> and *P*<sub>234</sub>, and again to obtain the single point *P*<sub>1234</sub>. This final point is B(*t*), the endpoint of your truncated curve. The startpoint is *P*<sub>1</sub> as before. The new control points are *P*<sub>12</sub> and *P*<sub>123</sub> the way we just constructed them.

Removing an initial part of the curve works the same way. So in two steps, you can trim both ends of your curve. You obtain a new set of control points which exactly (up to the numeric precision you use) describe a segment of your original curve, with no approximation or similar involved.

You can translate all of the geometric descriptions above into algebraic formulas, and in a perfect world you should come up with the results from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/879213/1468366) to the question you quoted.

Alas, this doesn't appear to be a perfect world. At the time of this writing, those formulas only used polynoms of degree two, so they could not describe endpoints on a third degree curve. The correct formula should be the following:

- *P'*<sub>1</sub> =
  *u*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>0</sub> *P*<sub>1</sub> +
  (*t*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>0</sub> +
  *u*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>0</sub> +
  *u*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>0</sub>) *P*<sub>2</sub> +
  (*t*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>0</sub> +
  *u*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>0</sub> +
  *t*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>0</sub>) *P*<sub>3</sub> +
  *t*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>0</sub> *P*<sub>4</sub>
- *P'*<sub>2</sub> =
  *u*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub> *P*<sub>1</sub> +
  (*t*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub> +
  *u*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub> +
  *u*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>) *P*<sub>2</sub> +
  (*t*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub> +
  *u*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub> +
  *t*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>) *P*<sub>3</sub> +
  *t*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub> *P*<sub>4</sub>
- *P'*<sub>3</sub> =
  *u*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub> *P*<sub>1</sub> +
  (*t*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub> +
  *u*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub> +
  *u*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>) *P*<sub>2</sub> +
  (*t*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub> +
  *u*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub> +
  *t*<sub>0</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>) *P*<sub>3</sub> +
  *t*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub> *P*<sub>4</sub>
- *P'*<sub>4</sub> =
  *u*<sub>1</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub> *P*<sub>1</sub> +
  (*t*<sub>1</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub> +
  *u*<sub>1</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub> +
  *u*<sub>1</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>) *P*<sub>2</sub> +
  (*t*<sub>1</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub> +
  *u*<sub>1</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub> +
  *t*<sub>1</sub>*u*<sub>1</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>) *P*<sub>3</sub> +
  *t*<sub>1</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub>*t*<sub>1</sub> *P*<sub>4</sub>

where *u*<sub>0</sub> = 1 − *t*<sub>0</sub> and *u*<sub>1</sub> = 1 − *t*<sub>1</sub>.

Note that in the parenthesized expressions, at least some of the terms are equal and can be combined. I did not do so as the formula as stated here will make the pattern clearer, I believe. You can simply execute those computations independently for the *x* and *y* directions to compute your new control points.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. But if I use the equations that you are referring to and that I use t0=0 and t1=1, I should have the complete bezier curve, so the 4 calculated points should be equal to the original 4 points but they are not. You get soemthing like this: xa=x1 (OK), xb=bx2 (bad), xc=bx1 (bad), xd=x2 (OK). I use HTML5 canvas method to draw the bezier curve by passing the 4 points and the curve is not right. Is there an error in the equations?

Comment: @Absolom, indeed there seems to be an error in that answer I linked to. Correct formula should now be included.

Comment: It works perfectly! Big thanks for taking the time to write all the formulas down. It might help other people as well. Thanks!

Comment: @MvG, thanks for pointing out that there was an error in my old answer (referenced by the asker). I have now fixed the error.