# How to get t for average distance of Bézier curve

Tags: ios, math, curve, bezier, linear-interpolation

I am calculating the interpolation position of Bézier curve by using the formula:

```
pow(1 - t, 2) * start + 2.0 * (1 - t) * t * control + t * t * end
```

The problem is that if I linear step the `t` by for example `0.1` per segment, the length of segment on the Bézier curve is not average.

Is there any way to get the corresponding array of `t` for getting average or approximately average length of the segment on the curve.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980166/equally-distribute-objects-across-a-bezier-curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want an approximate parametrization by arc length.

For the quadratic case, there is a closed-form expression for the arc length of a Bézier curve, but it is complicated and you still need table lookup. These papers discuss general techniques:

- [Approximate Arc Length Parametrization](http://www.visgraf.impa.br/sibgrapi96/trabs/abst/a14.html), in
  SIBGRAPI 1996.
- [Adaptive sampling of parametric curves](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/doc/g5011.ps.gz), in Graphics Gems V, 1995.
- [Computing the arc length of parametric curves](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/38.55155), in IEEE Computer Graphics and Applications, 1990.
- [Point-based methods for estimating the length of a parametric curve](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2005.10.001), in Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics, 2006.