# Get the distance covered from a curve line?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, curve, spline

Sorry for the newbie question. I want to create a curve way point line that the player will travel or move to by dragging, my question is how to know the total distance covered by the player based on the total length of the curved line? I can compare it as a Canvas slider UI with a value of 0 to 1 but instead of a straight, it can be a curved line.

Comment: This question is by far too broad and not trivial at all, in particular when you don´t provide *any* own attemps. What did you try so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: If you somehow have the equation of the line, this is defined by an integral.

Comment: You're looking for arc-length parameterization, something that's been covered extensively. Suggest reading would be http://stackoverflow.com/a/28764614/107090 and https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/5427

Comment: Note that "a curve" is not a real thing, it's just an abstract term used to mean "things that are not straight lines", so you'll need to make it explicit what kind of curve you're using before you can get a meaningful answer. Also, given the `unity3d` tag, it would be incredible if Unity didn't already have a function built in for that: did you look for one?

Answer (score 0):

The distance over a straight line is trivial, but in a general case, a curved line is not. To approximate distance over a curve the typical approach is to pick a smallish step, and iterate over your curve and sum partial distances for each step. The smaller the step the better the aproximation