# Length of Quadratic Curve

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have a Bezier Curve on an HTML5 Canvas and need to figure out the length of the curve. How can I do this easy?

Lets say :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(188, 130);
context.bezierCurveTo(140, 10, 388, 10, 388, 170);
context.lineWidth = 10;
```

How can I figure out the length of the curve I have created?

//T

Comment: You make what "easier"? There is absolutely no code in your question that shows "not-so-easy" way of achieving whatever you want.

Comment: Post your code with some more explanation

Comment: As the others say, needs code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to find it mathematically, using the parameters you pushed in.

Use this reference: [Calculate the length of a segment of a quadratic bezier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854907/calculate-the-length-of-a-segment-of-a-quadratic-bezier)