# How to draw a path partially in HTML5's canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Let's say I have curved path made using a serie of `bezierCurveTo()` calls. I'd like to make it appear progressively in an animation, by increasing the percentage of it that is drawn frame-after-frame. The problem is that I cannot find a standard way to draw only a part of a canvas path - would someon know of a good way (or even a tricky way) to achieve this?

Comment: This answer to a previous question may be useful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878862/drawing-part-of-a-bezier-curve-by-reusing-a-basic-bezier-curve-function

Comment: Oh, that's very helpful. Kudos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found a small library that does exactly that: https://github.com/camoconnell/lazy-line-painter

It relies on the Raphael lib (http://raphaeljs.com/), and the two put together do not make too big a payload.

Answer (score 3):

Sure...and Simon Porritt did all the hard math for us!

jsBezier is a small lib with a function: pointAlongCurveFrom(curve, location, distance) that will let you incrementally plot each point along your Bezier curve.

jsBezier is available on GitHub: https://github.com/sporritt/jsBezier

Comment: Thanks - however I tried this method (drawing points along the curve) with other environments and the result is unfortunately quite slow because of the high overdraw. This could be used until a way to use dashes gets standardized though (using dashed lines is an easy way to achieve this effect). Still open to other answers.

Comment: BTW, I haven't tried it, but I think Chrome now supports dashed lines with context.setLineDash([5]).

Comment: That's right - I'd like to stay in the fully compatible zone though :)